# Powershell WebAdministration Iterate through Applications / Virtual Directories for a given IIS Site

Tags: powershell, iis

I want to do some stuff with a Site and its Sub Applications (take them off line with app_offline.htm).

However I cannot find a way find or iterate through the virtual directories under a given site. I'm finding the site ok with

```
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites | Where {$_.Name -match $siteName}
```

However I'm not sure how to drill down into it's child apps / virtual directories.

I was thinking something like this...

```
Get-ChildItem -Path IIS:\Sites | Where {$_.Name -match $siteName} | `
ForEach{
    Write-Host $_.Name
    Get-WebVirtualDirectory -site $siteName | Foreach {
        Write-Host "Virtual Dir $_"
        #DO SOME STUFF
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Is that not working for you? What is the problem here? Also just to note, you don't need to escape a line break after a pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks Noah. I realised my mistake now. To answer my own question: Yes Get-VertualWebDirectory works, but NO it does not get Applicaitons under that site. I believe these "Sub sites" are only tired to the app pool and not the site. So I ended up just grabing the physical folders under that site.

```
Write-Host "Taking Site [$siteName] [$state]" -ForegroundColor Cyan

$targets = @($siteName)
$site = Get-WebSite | Where { $_.Name -eq $siteName }

$apps = Get-ChildItem $site.PhysicalPath `
| Where-Object { $_ -in $appNames } `
| ForEach {
    $targets += "$siteName/$_"
}

$targets | ForEach{
    Change-App-Status -app $_ -state $state
}
```